# understanding compareto() method in java

Tags: java, recursion, compareto

i came across a MIT lecture on recursion where they checked palindrome using recursion,and there they checked it using logic where they compare first and last alphabet and so on..
what i thought is something as follows

just a pseudo code:

```
    String original="abba";

    String reverse = "";
    for(int i=original.length()-1;i>=0;i--)
    {
        reverse+=new String(original.substring(i,i+1));
    }
    if(original.equals(reverse))
        System.out.println("palindrome");
    else
        System.out.println("not palindrome");
```

i have two doubts

- Is this logic better than recursion or conventional logic in terms of time complexity?
- How does `compareTo()` method checks if strings are equal? DOes it compare bytecode or something?

Comment: From the Java documentation: "Compares two strings lexicographically. The comparison is based on the Unicode value of each character in the strings." Whenever you need to know something, there are always a few basic searches you should be conducting before you ever ask.

Comment: Your code can't be compiled, please fix it and post a code that is compilable

Answer (score 3):

You should use `equals`, not `compareTo`, since compareTo returns an int and not a boolean as your `if` condition would expect. Alternately you can check `if (original.compareTo(reverse)==0)`, which means the Strings are equal.

As to how compareTo works, it compares each pair of characters having the same index, and returns the difference between the first non equal pair. If all are equal, 0 is returned.

Comment: You can use compare to also but the is and else should be switched. Comapre to returns the difference.

Comment: equals checks the object reference i guess? i want to check if the string content in same

Comment: @Farhanpatel No, `equals()` checks for equality as defined by it's [contract](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29), `==` checks for reference equality

Comment: yaa but my main concern is not the syntax.i want to know which method will be better recursion or this

Comment: @Farhanpatel When considering what solution to use for a problem, I would use a well-defined, time-tested method (`String.equals()`) that's served programmers well for almost 20 years rather than my own solution I plinked together 2 minutes ago

Comment: @Farhanpatel Also, to answer the time complexity question, `String.equals()` is `O(n)` in the average/worst case, `O(1)` in the best case, see http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u6/jdk/file/8c2c5d63a17e/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java line 974

Comment: how equals() method work i mean does it loop over each alphabet to check like a for loop or something else?

Comment: @Aeshang yes. I editted my answer. Sometimes I sin by posting my answers in parts, especially when I'm interrupted by the outside world :)

Comment: @Eran Then the down vote also goes away when you are wiling to fix your mistakes ;)

Comment: @Farhanpatel equals() loops over the characters of both Strings and compares each pair of characters with the same index. It stops when it finds the first non-equal character. In that sense, equals and compareTo have the same complexity, but the operator equals calls is `!=` (not equals) while compareTo calls `-` (minus).

Answer (score 1):

CompareTo will loop over each character in the strings. If the character is bigger/smaller (based on alphabetical order) it will return a positive/negative number.

Therefore when `string1.compareTo(reverseString)==0` the two strings are the same. (no single letter is smaller/bigger than the one in the other string)

Since you didn't provide a recursive implementation its hard to say anything about performance characteristics.

Answer (score 1):

> *Is this logic better than recursion or conventional logic in terms of*
>   time complexity?

Assuming you are using the following recursive method,

```
public static boolean isPal(String s)
    {
        if(s.length() == 0 || s.length() == 1)
            return true; 
        if(s.charAt(0) == s.charAt(s.length()-1))
            return isPal(s.substring(1, s.length()-1));
        return false;
    }
```

Time Complexity: [O(n)](http://www.cs.bilkent.edu.tr/~gunduz/teaching/cs201/slides/Recitation4.pdf)

**equals:**

```
public boolean equals(Object paramObject)
  {
    if (this == paramObject) {
      return true;
    }
    if ((paramObject instanceof String))
    {
      String str = (String)paramObject;
      int i = this.value.length;
      if (i == str.value.length)
      {
        char[] arrayOfChar1 = this.value;
        char[] arrayOfChar2 = str.value;
        for (int j = 0; i-- != 0; j++) {
          if (arrayOfChar1[j] != arrayOfChar2[j]) {
            return false;
          }
        }
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
  }
```

The complexity of your program is : O(n)+O(n)=O(n)

---

> How does compareTo() method checks if strings are equal? DOes it
>   compare bytecode or something?

**compareTo:** returns 0 if the two strings are same or else it returns the difference, integer difference (i.e difference of Unicode values) of first non-matching characters,

It does so by comparing characters at same positions of two strings

```
  public int compareTo(String paramString)
  {
    int i = this.value.length;
    int j = paramString.value.length;
    int k = Math.min(i, j);
    char[] arrayOfChar1 = this.value;
    char[] arrayOfChar2 = paramString.value;
    for (int m = 0; m < k; m++)
    {
      int n = arrayOfChar1[m];
      int i1 = arrayOfChar2[m];
      if (n != i1) {
        return n - i1;
      }
    }
    return i - j;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

1: is this logic better than recursion or coventional logic in terms of time complexity
In Java recursion is fairly expensive compared to iteration (in general) because it requires the allocation of a new stack frame.
If you're using a functional language like C, recursion might be faster. If you're using an imperative language like Java, iteration is probably faster.

2:how compareTo() method checks if strings are equal

The value 0 if the argument is a string lexicographically equal to this string; a value less than 0 if the argument is a string lexicographically greater than this string; and a value greater than 0 if the argument is a string lexicographically less than this string.